# Elixir (UndefinedFunctionError) function in test env

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have this code in the module

```
alias Commerce.Cart.{Cart, CartMaster}

@spec call(Cart.t()) :: Cart.t()
def call(cart) do
  cart
  |> add_pets_adjustments()
  |> CartMaster.recalculate_credit()
end
```

when I run the test I get this error

`** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Commerce.Cart.CartMaster.recalculate_credit/1 is undefined (module Commerce.Cart.CartMaster is not available)`

I checked the CartMaster module and the name is correct

```
defmodule Commerce.Cart.CartMaster do
  #  ...
  def recalculate_credit(cart) do
    cart
    |> remove_existing_credit_adjustment
    |> remove_applied_credit()
    |> apply_credit()
    |> add_credit_adjustment()
  end
end
```

I also changed the function call to

```
def call(cart) do
  cart
  |> add_pets_adjustments()
  |> Commerce.Cart.CartMaster.recalculate_credit()
end
```

And got the same error

I checked in the "_build/test/lib/app/ebin" and I found the `Elixir.Commerce.Cart.CartMaster.beam` file

calling the function to check modules loaded inside the call function

```
:app
|> :application.get_key(:modules)
|> elem(1)
|> Enum.filter(fn e -> String.contains?(to_string(e), "Commerce.Cart") end)
|> IO.inspect(label: :modules)
```

the module shows in the list

```
modules: [Commerce.Cart.Adjustment, Commerce.Cart.Cart, Commerce.Cart.CartMaster, ...]
```

running the app in development mode and doing manual testing works just fine,
I'm out of ideas of what it can be.

Comment: The issue is most likely with your `mix.exs`. Do you use custom compilation paths for different environments? In any case, please share your `mix.exs`.

Comment: the mix.exs is the defult
```
elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
....
# Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]
```

Comment: all modules files are under /lib directory

Comment: All looks good. Would you mind to try `defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["test/support", "lib"]`? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: I changed and for some reason running the tests local works, but in the CI I'm getting this
```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Commerce.Cart.CartMaster.recalculate_credit/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:
     
           * recalculate_credit/1
     
     code: }} = RemovePet.call(cart, payload)
```